# importing mxnet in python window 10 using intellj

Tags: python, intellij-idea, mxnet

when i `import mxnet` using `import mxnet as mx` in intellij (python) then compier generate error

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"

and shows trackcall shows

> line 1 "import mxnet as mx" in test.python 
>   mxnet already in env/lib

Comment: Hi Ali, can you provide a minimally reproducible example of what you are trying to accomplish and describe the environment you are running from (python version, os, mxnet version)

Comment: windows 10 single home, virtual env , python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

You might be having PyCharm configuration issues, so I recommend you check things from the command line first. Open up a command prompt and activate the virtual env using `\path\to\env\Scripts\activate`. Confirm that MXNet has been installed in this environment by listing the pip packages with `pip list` and looking for `mxnet`. Use `pip install mxnet` if you don't see it in the list of installed packages. Now run a Python interpreter with `python` and try `import mxnet`.

If this works, you now need to ensure that PyCharm is using the correct Python environment, as there maybe multiple environments installed on the system. And instructions can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Pip did not download correct version of MXnet for my version of CUDA (10.2).

The DLL which is not found is for the CUDA version for which MXNet was downloaded.

I solved the problem by accessing the repository and directly downloading the correct package.

In my case it was `mxnet_cu102mkl-2.0.0b20200504-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl`.

It worked normally after this.